# How to store std::sqrt in std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, function-pointers

[`std::sqrt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt) is of type `std::complex<T>(const std::complex<T>&)`. Why can't I store it in this `std::function`? The error I get is:

> error: conversion from ‘’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function(const std::complex&)>’ requested

[Run it here:](https://onlinegdb.com/rJhEwKR4L)

```
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using Complex = std::complex<double>;
    std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = std::sqrt;
    std::cout << "sqrt(4): " << f(std::complex<double>(4,0)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the line in your code:

```
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = std::sqrt;
```

You must take into account that [`std::sqrt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt) is **not** an ordinary function but a *function template*:

```
template<class T>
complex<T> sqrt(const complex<T>& z);
```

You defined `Complex` in terms of the [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class template:

```
using Complex = std::complex<double>;
```

Since `std::complex` contains the *member type* `value_type` that corresponds to the passed *template argument* (i.e., `double` in this case), you can just do:

```
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = std::sqrt<Complex::value_type>;
```

This is equivalent to directly passing `double` as template argument to `std::sqrt()`:

```
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = std::sqrt<double>;
```

However, the former is more generic than the latter because it allows you to change `std::complex`'s template argument – e.g., using `int` or `float` instead of `double` – without having to edit the source code corresponding to the assignment.

---

Since C++14 you can also wrap the call to `std::sqrt()` by means of a *generic lambda* and assign this lambda to the `std::function` object:

```
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = [](auto const& x) { 
   return std::sqrt(x); 
};
```

Comment: If my damn clion didn't had problems, I would have been first. ;->

Comment: @Superlokkus use vim next time.

Comment: Hmm... lambda trick is C++11, it's the "auto" argument what came later

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, but the `auto` turns the *lambda* into a *generic lambda*, doesn't it? As far as I understand, that is a [C++14 feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Generic_lambdas).

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the template parameter for the assignment.

```
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using Complex = std::complex<double>;
    std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f = std::sqrt<double>;
    std::cout << "sqrt(4): " << f(std::complex<double>(4,0)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```