# Can't use complex C++ functions in std::function #2

Tags: c++, function

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547115/how-to-store-stdsqrt-in-stdfunction)

For reasons unknown to me, my code stopped working today. For preimplemented functions I have a relay code like this

```
Math_Node& Function_Manager::relay_complex_to_std(Math_Node& arg, std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> f) const{
    if( arg.children_.size() != 1 ){
        throw std::runtime_error("Function expects exactly one argument.");
    }
    evaluate(*arg.children_[0]);
    if( std::holds_alternative<Complex>(arg.children_[0]->data_) ){
        arg.data_ = f(std::get<Complex>(arg.children_[0]->data_));
        arg.children_.clear();
    }
    return arg;
}
```

with the types

```
using Decimal       = double;
using Complex       = std::complex<Decimal>;
```

This can be called by a different function like

```
Math_Node& Function_Manager::sqrt(Math_Node& arg) const{
    //return relay_complex_to_std(arg, std::sqrt<Complex::value_type>);
    return relay_complex_to_std(arg, [](Complex a){return std::sqrt(a);});
}
```

The commented line stopped working with the error message

```
In member function ‘Numeric_Calculator::Math_Node& Numeric_Calculator::Function_Manager::sqrt(Numeric_Calculator::Math_Node&) const’:
functionmanager.cpp:214:72: error: 
no matching function for call to ‘Numeric_Calculator::Function_Manager::relay_complex_to_std(Numeric_Calculator::Math_Node&, unresolved overloaded function type>) const’
         return relay_complex_to_std(arg, std::sqrt<Complex::value_type>);
```

Why is the function type not resolved? It works when I put it in a lambda.

Compiler:

> g++-9 --version
>   g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-17ubuntu1~18.04.1) 9.2.1 20191102

edit:

Thanks to Jarod42 for pointing out the overload with `valarray`. You can see for yourself that de-commenting the below line will result in the same error

```
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
//#include <valarray>

using Complex = std::complex<double>;

Complex relay(Complex arg, std::function<Complex(Complex)> f){
    return f(arg);
}

int main(){
    std::function<Complex(Complex)> f = std::sqrt<Complex::value_type>;
    std::cout << std::sqrt(4.0) << "\n";
    std::cout << relay(Complex(-2,0), std::sqrt<Complex::value_type>) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another (inferirior) alternative to lambda is the explicit cast: `static_cast<Complex (*)(const Complex&)>(std::sqrt)`.

Comment: Well now that I know what's causing it I managed to not include the "malicious" header, so the code can stay as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::sqrt<double>` might be ambiguous, it might be

- [`std::sqrt(std::complex<double>)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt)
- [`std::sqrt(std::valarray<double>)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/sqrt)
- <strike>[`std::sqrt(Integral)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt)</strike> (not accepting `double`)

And whereas `std::complex` one might be converted to the expected `std::function`, name resolution doesn't take that conversion into account.

See [Address of an overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) for more details.

Comment: Why is the integral version ambiguous here? It's overloaded, but not a template.

Comment: @Timo: *"4) A set of overloads or **a function template** accepting an argument of any integral type. Equivalent to (2) (the argument is cast to double)."*. It **might** be template.

Comment: @Timo: But you probably right though, as it should be SFINAE for integral type...

Comment: It's the overload to std::valarray that causes the error. The overload with the Integral types work fine. I guess somewhere along a standard header also includes <valarray> because that leads to an error in a small test code.