# How to use std::sqrt as std::function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, function-pointers

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    // This works.
    std::function<float(float)> f = [](auto const& x) {return std::sqrt(x);};   
    
    // This also works. Why this works?!
    using Complex = std::complex<double>;
    std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> g = std::sqrt<double>;
    
    // All of the following doesn't work.
    // error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
    // to non-scalar type ‘std::function<float(float)>’ requested
    std::function<float(float)> a = std::sqrtf<float>;
    std::function<float(float)> b = std::sqrt<float>;
    std::function<float(float)> c = std::sqrt;
    std::function<double(double)> d = std::sqrt<double>;
}
```

Considering the [std::sqrt reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt), I am really confused as to why the one involving complex works, and why the other ones do not work.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547115/how-to-store-stdsqrt-in-stdfunction), but, I am not interested in using `std::complex`, and, the OP from this question specifically asks for `std::complex`, and, in contrast, I'd like to work only with `float` or `double` (or real valued, not complex).

What's going on?
What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `std::sqrt` for floats is not a template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Considering the std::sqrt reference,

You're looking the wrong `std::sqrt` page: it's the page of the non-template version.

If you use `std::sqrt<double>` and `std::sqrt<float>` functions, you're using the **template** version of `std::sqtr`, that is referenced in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/sqrt).

As you can see, `std::sqrt<T>`

```
template< class T >
complex<T> sqrt( const complex<T>& z );
```

receive a `std::complex<T>` and return a `std::complex<T>`.

So when you write

```
std::function<float(float)> f = [](auto const& x) {return std::sqrt(x);};
```

works because the lambda call (`std::sqrt(x)`, where `x` is a `float`) the not template function.

When you write

```
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> g = std::sqrt<double>;
```

works because `std::sqrt<double>` is the template version of `std::sqrt` that receive a `Complex const &` (`std::complex<double> const &`) and return a `Complex const &`

But when you write something as

```
std::function<float(float)> b = std::sqrt<float>;
std::function<double(double)> d = std::sqrt<double>;
```

you pass function receiving and returning a complex to `std::function` waiting for function receiving and returning a simple (not complex) floating point type.

To make it works, you have to use the non-template version of `std::sqrt` (so no `<float>` and no `<double>`) and cast the right pointer type (to select the right version of the `std::sqrt` non-template but overloaded version). This works also for `c`.

```
std::function<float(float)> b = (float(*)(float))std::sqrt;
std::function<float(float)> c = (float(*)(float))std::sqrt;
std::function<double(double)> d = (double(*)(double))std::sqrt;
```

For `a` the problem

```
std::function<float(float)> a = std::sqrtf<float>;
```

is different; you have to remove the template part (`<float>`), given that `std::sqrtf` isn't a template function.

So should works (`std::sqrtf` isn't overloaded, so no cast should be required, given there isn't ambiguity)

```
std::function<float(float)> a = std::sqrtf;
```

Unfortunately I see that this doesn't works with clang++ and with g++. As far I understand it's because `cmath` doesn't put `sqrtf` inside the `std` namespace (and seems to me that g++ and clang++ are not conforming).

So (with g++ and clang++) works

```
std::function<float(float)> a = sqrtf;
```

Comment: He linked to the right `std::sqrt` page, but it's probably not the one he _read_

Comment: @MooingDuck - Yes and no: he linked one of the two pages he should read.

Answer (score 7):

The floating-point overloads of `std::sqrt()` and `std::sqrtf()` are not templates, so these forms are invalid syntax:

```cpp
std::function<float(float)> a = std::sqrtf<float>;
// and
std::function<double(double)> d = std::sqrt<double>;
```

This form:

```cpp
std::function<float(float)> c = std::sqrt;
```

Would be okay, except that `std::sqrt()` is overloaded, so the name can't decay to a single pointer like it would if it wasn't overloaded.

In order to remove the ambiguity of which overload to use, you need to cast the function to the correct type:

```cpp
std::function<float(float)> works = static_cast<float(*)(float)>(std::sqrt);
```

But as you can see, the syntax is a little verbose, which is why the lambda version is the go-to way to do this.

The reason this form works:

```cpp
std::function<Complex(const Complex&)> g = std::sqrt<double>;
```

Is because the `std::complex` version of `std::sqrt()` is a template, where the template parameter is the underlying type of the complex object.

Comment: Note that `std::sqrtf()` is not overloaded, so `std::function<float(float)> a = std::sqrtf;` [should work](https://ideone.com/Gj5yms)